# How to respond to "How much funding will you bring?" as an interview question for a faculty job?

Tags: funding, interview, faculty-application

What are the possible answers for such interview question assuming a new graduate with no funds!
How much funding you will bring to the department?

Comment: "All of it! I shall crush my enemies, see them driven before me, and hear the lamentations of their postdocs!"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an invitation to discuss your plans for obtaining external funding.  They want your answers to questions like the following:

- What agencies fund research like yours?
- What projects do you have that you think would be successful in gaining external funding?
- Why do you think you would be successful?  Can you point to similar (but not too similar) projects that have been funded?  Why would a funding agency agree your work is worthy of support?  Why would they agree that you are a qualified person to carry out the work, and that your project is likely to actually produce useful results?  How would you convince them?  What supporting evidence would you use?
- How large would those grants be likely to be?  How do you know?
- When do you propose to begin applying for such grants?  Is there anything specific that needs to happen first?
- Do you have collaborators in mind with whom you might co-apply?  Have you discussed this with them?

Comment: So the original question is not about how much do you have "currently"? And how would someone know how much funding he can get, and prove that, assuming there wasn't a previous record of PI grants?

Comment: @Thomas: The question may have been meant to ask about how much you have. But if you don't have any, don't just say "none"; talk about how you're going to get it. Of course you can't prove that you will get such-and-such an amount, but you want to make a convincing case that you have an excellent chance of obtaining significant funding.